# function returns some pointers as NULL

Tags: c, function, pointers

I have the following data structure:

```
struct Stack {
    Vector* m_intArray; /*vector is stored here*/
    int m_numOfElements;
};

struct Vector {
    int* m_intArray; /*pointer to array of ints, data stored here*/
    int m_intArrayCurrentSize;
    int m_intArrayCapacity;
    int m_blockSize; 
    int m_initialSize;
};
```

The vector structure is written in a different file (vector.c) with function

```
Vector* VectorCreate(size_t _initialSize, size_t _blockSize)
```

which creates the vector structure and allocates memory for the array of ints in it. In the file stack.c I've written the function

```
Stack* StackCreate(size_t _initialSize, size_t _blockSize)
```

which creates the stack structure and calls VectorCreate in the "m_intArray" field of stack. When I call StackCreate from main, I see uding the debugger that inside the function, everything is OK and there is memory allocated for all three pointers (pointer to stack, pointer to vector and pointer to int)

```
(gdb) p stackPtr
$11 = (Stack *) 0x603010
(gdb) p stackPtr->m_intArray
$12 = (Vector *) 0x603030
(gdb) p stackPtr->m_intArray->m_intArray
$13 = (int *) 0x603050
```

When the function ends and returns the Stack pointer back to main, the int* pointer is nulled.

```
(gdb) p testStack
$14 = (Stack *) 0x603030
(gdb) p testStack->m_intArray
$15 = (Vector *) 0x603050
(gdb) p testStack->m_intArray->m_intArray
$16 = (int *) 0x0
```

I can't seem to find the reason it happens, pretty much clueless in this case. Never ran into it before, will appreciate your help.

Heres the Stack Create

```
Stack* StackCreate(size_t _initialSize, size_t _blockSize)
{
    if (_initialSize == 0 && _blockSize == 0)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    Stack* stackPtr = ((Stack*)malloc(sizeof(Stack)));
    if (stackPtr == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    stackPtr->m_intArray = VectorCreate(_initialSize, _blockSize);
    if (stackPtr->m_intArray == NULL)
    {
        free(stackPtr);
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code for the create functions?

Comment: Now I noticed that I forgot to retunr the pointer in the create function :)
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're returning the wrong pointer. Notice how in the first GDB segment, the stack pointer is `0x603010`, but in the second segment, it's `0x603030`, which is the vector pointer in the first chunk.

Comment: Just noticed it, pretty weird, added the stack create code